# iPhoto-style sidebar

Tags: cocoa, interface, interface-builder

I'm trying to achieve this "effect" in cocoa (photo taken from Things.app from Cultured Code):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PXSourceList](http://github.com/perspx/PXSourceList) makes creating a source list very easy.

Comment: Whoa!  That's nice.  I'll look into this one when I get the chance.

Answer (score 4):

Try using an NSTableView or NSOutlineView with the selection style set to source list:

```
[outlineView setSelectionHighlightStyle: NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList]
```

Then create a custom NSCell class that displays your icon and text.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this when I get the chance.