# How to mimic Finder left tree in cocoa app?

Tags: user-interface, macos, treeview, finder

I really like a look of left tree in Finder (Mac OS X >= 10.5). That with a blue background color and "DEVICES" and "PLACES" dropdowns. I'd like category view in my app to look the same. But since I'm new to Mac OS X app development, I can't figure out if it's just a OutlineView? If so is there a predefined color scheme like in finder?

Comment: This is called a SourceList. See similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241507/how-would-one-implement-a-sidebar-similar-to-mail-itunes-finder-etc-in-cocoa-ib, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670727/trouble-creating-an-itunes-style-source-list-in-cocoa, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133281/iphoto-style-sidebar

Answer (score 3):

It's a source list.  See the source list section of the [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGWindows/XHIGWindows.html)

To make one in IB, you add a vertical split view with a thin divider.  Into the left pane you put an outline view and set the highlight style to "source list".  That will automatically give you the correct background colour.